# Erro ao executar update com subconsulta

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tenho a seguinte situação, preciso efetuar um update em diversos campos com base no retorno de uma subconsulta que retorna um código principal. Essa subconsulta está é feita com join em duas tabelas para obtenção do código.
Ao efeturar, tenho o seguinte erro:

Mensagem 512, Nível 16, Estado 1, Linha 24
A subconsulta retornou mais de 1 valor. Isso não é permitido quando a subconsulta segue um =, !=, <, <= , >, >= ou quando ela é usada como uma expressão.

Essa é a consulta:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
UPDATE Produto SET TpProduto = 'C' WHERE IdProduto = (
SELECT DISTINCT(p.IdProduto)
FROM dbo.Produto p 
JOIN dbo.CodigoProduto  cp ON cp.IdProduto = p.IdProduto
WHERE cp.CdChamada IN(
'3VT9200-4ED30                 ',
'3VT9225-6AC00                 ',
'5SX11207                      ',
'6ES73921AJ000AA0              ',
'8910427                       ',
'9676812                       ',
'CON000280                     '

 )

)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

esse select retornar mais de um valor

```
SELECT DISTINCT(p.IdProduto)
```

como comparar

```
WHERE IdProduto = (vários valores)
```

esse pedaço aqui precisa retornar apenas um valor

```
SELECT DISTINCT(p.IdProduto)
FROM dbo.Produto p 
JOIN dbo.CodigoProduto  cp ON cp.IdProduto = p.IdProduto
WHERE cp.CdChamada IN(
'3VT9200-4ED30                 ',
'3VT9225-6AC00                 ',
'5SX11207                      ',
'6ES73921AJ000AA0              ',
'8910427                       ',
'9676812                       ',
'CON000280                     '

 )
```

verifica se não é isso.

Comment: É isso mesmo, preciso comparar vários retornos, os que estão na subconsulta e atualizar os mesmos. Esse banco que estou mexendo é confuso, ele gera o código em tabelas diferentes e como são muitos dados pensei em pegar o retorno da subconsulta e ir atualizando.

Comment: Já resolvi, basta mudar a instrução de = para in na primeira consulta.

Comment: marca como respondido, para ajudar outras pessoas.